# How to find the unmatched records where only partial records matches the conditions?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table table_A

```
ID  EMP
1   9999
1   1
2   9999
2   2
2   3
3   9999
3   9999
3   4
3   4
3   4
4   9999
4   9999
4   9999
5   5
5   6
```

I want the records where where emp <> 9999 but this case should be satisfied not for all the id. So my expected output will be

```
id emp
1   1
2   2
2   3
3   4
3   4
3   4
```

Here records with id 4 and 5 are not present because their distinct emp values are either 9999 only or any other values rather than 9999

I tried but not getting the desired results:

```
SELECT ID, EMP
FROM table_a
WHERE ID IN (
  SELECT ID
  FROM table_a
  WHERE EMP <> 9999
  GROUP BY ID
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EMP <> 9999 THEN EMP END) > 0
)
AND EMP <> 9999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show all rows where emp is not 9999 and exists a row for the same id with emp = 9999.

```
select id, emp
from table_a
where emp <> 9999
and id in (select id from table_a where emp = 9999)
order by id, emp;
```

(Of course, you can use an `EXISTS` clause instead of the `IN` clause, if you like that better.)

Comment: this will also show the result for id = 5; which i don't need

Comment: Ah, sorry, you are right of course, I got it backwards. I've corrected my answer.

Comment: `EXISTS` is so faster than `IN`. I used it

Comment: `EXISTS` and `IN` should result in the same execution plan for this simple query. If this is not the case, then this is a surprising flaw in the DBMS optimizer. Did you look at the execution plan or how do you know? Don't run the `IN` query first and the `EXISTS` query afterwards and compare the run times. The second query will be faster, because it can read data from cache instead of from disk.

Answer (score 0):

Using `QUALIFY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
QUALIFY COUNT_IF(emp = 9999) OVER(PARTITION BY ID) > 0
   AND emp <> 9999;
```

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(id INT, EMP INT);

INSERT INTO tab(id, emp)
VALUES (1, 9999),(1, 1)
  ,(2, 9999),(2, 2),(2, 3)
  ,(3, 9999),(3, 9999),(3, 4),(3, 4),(3, 4)
  ,(4, 9999),(4, 9999),(4, 9999)
  ,(5, 5)
  ,(5, 6);
```

Output:

| ID | EMP |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 4 |